Android - problems with "com.android.skia.shaders_cache" file
Recently i bought a new phone, installed a game in working with and got a really dumb trouble. Few days of digging into this problem and i found a reason of crash: com.android.skia.shaders_cache
A huge question: how can i turn off shader caching? The shaders are being created by the game itself, MAYBE some conflict (doesn't happen on all phones).
Had no luck in googling...
